# Embedding HTML files with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I'm looking into migrating a large, homegrown build script for one of our projects to webpack.

One feature it has is it traverses a `/views` directory and copies the contents of the html files into a main `index.html` file. This allows us to easily use KnockoutJS's templating feature without putting everything in one file ourselves. Something like this:

```
for relative_path, full_path in walk(os.path.join(base, "views")):
    with open(full_path) as f:
        index.append("""<script type="text/html" id="{0}">""".format(relative_path))
        index.extend(f)
        index.append("</script>")
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like `require('./views')` and have it embed each `.html` file as `<script type="text/html" id="views/foo">...</script>`, injecting the text into the script tag and setting the `id` to the filepath. We have almost 100 different templates, so I'd like to avoid `require()`ing them individually.

Can I configure `html-loader` or `html-webpack-plugin` to do this? I'm wondering if I'll have to write my own webpack plugin or if there's a way I can configure an existing plugin to do what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this using [require.context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#require-context) and the [html loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader).

```
function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}
// requires and returns html files in the views directory
var modules = requireAll(require.context("./views", true, /^\.html$/));
modules.forEach(function(htmlTemplate){ 
   // code to add each template to document.body
}
```